# On what dataset was haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml trained?

Tags: opencv, cascade, haar-classifier

I'm trying to make my own cascade file, but so far with little success, because of the time it takes to train one decent file (2 days) I don't want to spend months failing. In the example files of Opencv, there is the  haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml file.

my question is: Does anybody know on what data was this trained?

I can see that it was 22stages, but I would like to see the images used to better understand how it was made.

I have little hopes since this must be kept quite secret, but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally, it was trained on the frontal CALTECH dataset in 1999 (see J. Howse "openCV 4 for secret agent", second edition, Packt, Chapter 3, [pages 101-102](https://books.google.fr/books?id=b1qWDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=opencv%20haar%20cascade%20original%20training%20dataset&source=bl&ots=eXx7zOlcyI&sig=ACfU3U07b8VG2G3pFQgyGFEfRccqEJsD_g&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM09-8hJ_qAhVCyxoKHVzpBhwQ6AEwDHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=opencv%20haar%20cascade%20original%20training%20dataset&f=false)). It is not easy to find this dataset, but you can use the more recent [Caltech 10,000 Web face](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech_10K_WebFaces/)

**update** actually on the [github site of the book cited](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/OpenCV-4-for-Secret-Agents-Second-Edition) there are some details to find and process the dataset. The dataset itself can be found [here](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/faces/faces.tar)

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know how I miss that, but thank you ever soo much.